# Run Instruments 4.3 from the cmd line?

Tags: ios, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I'm having trouble running Instruments 4.3 from the cmd line. I believe it's picking up my older 4.2 version which is still installed. How do I get Instruments 4.3 to install and launch my App then run UIAutomation against it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're specifying the `-w` parameter but not supplying a device ID. If you're trying to run from your app in the simulator, then just leave out the `-w` like so.

```
xcrun instruments -v \
  -t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate \
  /Users/cliff/Src/MyApp/build/MyApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app \
  -e UIASCRIPT /Users/cliff/Src/MyApp/UIAutomation/automation-test.js \
  -e UIARESULTSPATH /Users/cliff/Src/MyApp/build/uiautomation
```

If you really are trying to run this automation script on the device, then you can quickly grab the device ID by using [this script I wrote](http://cocoamanifest.net/linked/2012/05/ruby-script-to-grab-id-of-plugged-in-ios-device.html). Hand that ID in to the `-w` parameter and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out but I'm still having issues. I installed the command line tools from preferences -> Downloads and ran

```
xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

I then ran:

```
xcrun instruments -v -t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -w /Users/cliff/Src/MyApp/build/MyApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app -e UIASCRIPT /Users/cliff/Src/MyApp/UIAutomation/automation-test.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /Users/cliff/Src/MyApp/build/uiautomation
```

I'm pretty sure this picks up the current version of Instruments cmd line tools since I've also moved my /Developer folder out of my PATH. I sell keep getting: "Instruments Usage Error : Device failed to become ready for use." So what gives??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments`

How about this:
`/Applications/Xcode.app//Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments`

Comment: That opens the application from the bundle. I'm wondering where the "instruments" cmd line command is or if it is now deprecated or what.

Comment: Ooh wait! I just looked under downloads in the preferences pane and it seems I haven't downloaded the command line tools yet!

Comment: No that didn't work either! I keep getting: "Instruments Usage Error : Device failed to become ready for use."

Comment: I missed your edit and that would also probably have worked. I still keep getting the device not ready error. :(